# WCF Server accepts TLS 1.0 connections

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl, tls1.2

I have a very "simple" problem. I have a WCF-Server which should only be accepting TLS 1.2 connections. But every time i connect to it trough firefox or any browser it uses TLS 1.0.

.NET Framework-Version is 4.6.1 so it should support TLS 1.2.
Here's my app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="WCFServer.Properties.Settings.ConnectionString" connectionString="SomeConnectionString" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>          
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="TestNetTcpBinding">
      <reliableSession enabled="true" />
      <security>
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" algorithmSuite="Basic256Sha256Rsa15" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MyCustomAttributeBehavior">
      <Validator />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="DefaultBehavior">
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpsGetUrl="mex" policyVersion="Default" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<extensions>
  <behaviorExtensions>
    <add name="Validator" type="WCFServer.RightAttribute.MyBehaviorSection, WCFServer, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  </behaviorExtensions>
</extensions>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior" name="WCFServer.Services.Implementations.BusinessService">
    <endpoint address="ProductService" behaviorConfiguration="MyCustomAttributeBehavior"
      binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TestNetTcpBinding"
      contract="WCFServer.Services.Interfaces.IProductService" />
    <endpoint address="UserService" behaviorConfiguration="MyCustomAttributeBehavior"
      binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TestNetTcpBinding"
      contract="WCFServer.Services.Interfaces.IUserService" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://SomeHost/WCFService/Service" />
        <add baseAddress="https://SomeHost/WCFService/Service" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="NHibernate" publicKeyToken="aa95f207798dfdb4" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.4000" newVersion="4.1.0.4000" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

I hope i didnt **** up formatting of the XML too bad. Sorry for that.
I put it in a console application to test things out.
Here's my main method (where I try to set the SecurityProtocol to only TLS 1.2)

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(BusinessService));
host.Open();    
Console.WriteLine("Services Ready");
Console.WriteLine("Press any button to close services.");
Console.Read();
host.Close();
Environment.Exit(0);
```

My class `BusinessService` implements both `IUserService` and `IProductService`.

You can ignore the `MyCustomAttributeBehavior`. Just some "Interceptor" stuff, which shouldn't matter.

EDIT: Certificate is OK. Also firefox says that. 
Does the certificate have to meet any special requirements? I don't think so but I'm not sure.

I already tried setting the `SecurityProtocol` before and after the `host.Open()`. Both didnt work.

Any help is appreciate.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` is only used for opening connections, not for connections being received. If you're using an HTTP-based binding (such as BasicHttpsBinding), then the SSL/TLS version used will depend on the HTTP.SYS configuration (self-hosted or in IIS), which in turn depends on the global SCHANNEL settings on the machine.

In this case, you're using NetTcp, which last I remember does not use SSL/TLS at all.